# What is the best way to encrypt data in Android Intent between two apps?

Tags: android, encryption, android-intent, cryptography, libsodium

I am trying to encrypt the data between two apps. I am creating only one of the apps and SDK which will be used by a demo app that will be sharing data with my app using intents. The demo app will implement the SDK which will be used to do call my app.

I decided on using lazysodium (https://github.com/terl/lazysodium-java) and using Public/Private keypairs (generateKeyPair()) to encrypt and decrypt data.

**My questions:**

How do I go about sharing the public keys between the two apps without jumping back and forth between the apps using intents to share the keys? I would prefer to do key sharing and then encrypt the message in the same intent call?

Is there a better way to do it? I have searched a lot and cannot figure it out.

Comment: Check for ContentProvider as well.

Comment: @DarShan could you please explain the last comment a bit further, I do not get it.

Comment: There is no other way than essentially performing a handshake between the 2 apps. But why would you want to perform encryption for data stored in intents? Intents are already protected by the Android OS (as long as you're using explicit intents).